# Get the "map" object in Mapbox-GL react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mapbox-gl-js

I have a code like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps'

MapboxGL.setAccessToken( 'xxxx' )

export default class DebugMap extends Component {

  render() {
    return <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
        
      <MapboxGL.MapView
          ref={(c) => (this.map = c)}
          onPress={v => this.map.moveTo( 40, 10 )}
          style={{flex: 1}}>

          <MapboxGL.Camera
            zoomLevel={10}
            centerCoordinate={[50, 20]}
          />
        </MapboxGL.MapView>

    </View>
  }
}
```

The map is displayed normally an centered around `50, 20`, but if I press it, an error is thrown:

```
TypeError: _this3.map.moveTo is not a function. (In '_this3.map.moveTo(48, 11)', '_this3.map.moveTo' is undefined)
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

if I do `console.info( 'load map', this.map )` I see this in the console:

```
{"_callbackMap": Map {"setHandledMapChangedEvents_347" => {"reject": [Function anonymous], "resolve": [Function anonymous]}}, "_nativeModuleName": "RCTMGLMapView", "_nativeRef": {"_children": [[ReactNativeFiberHostComponent]], "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157560, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 0.308383971452713, "actualStartTime": 174949282.375041, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childLanes": 0, "dependencies": null, "elementType": "RCTMGLAndroidTextureMapView", "firstEffect": null, "flags": 132, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function ref], "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.2550770044326782, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [Circular], "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 1.2080000042915344, "type": "RCTMGLAndroidTextureMapView", "updateQueue": null}, "_nativeTag": 12959, "viewConfig": {"Commands": [Object], "NativeProps": [Object], "bubblingEventTypes": undefined, "directEventTypes": [Object], "uiViewClassName": "RCTMGLAndroidTextureMapView", "validAttributes": [Object]}}, "_onAndroidCallback": [Function bound _onAndroidCallback], "_onChange": [Function bound _onChange], "_onDebouncedRegionDidChange": [Function debounced], "_onDebouncedRegionWillChange": [Function debounced], "_onLayout": [Function bound _onLayout], "_onLongPress": [Function bound _onLongPress], "_onPress": [Function bound _onPress], "_preRefMapMethodQueue": [], "_reactInternalInstance": {}, "_reactInternals": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157251, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157243, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": null, "actualDuration": 1.7872289419174194, "actualStartTime": 174946767.76704, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childLanes": 1, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Function DebugMap], "firstEffect": [FiberNode], "flags": 0, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "lastEffect": [FiberNode], "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": [Object], "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 9.36361500620842, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [DebugMap], "tag": 1, "treeBaseDuration": 134.84192779660225, "type": [Function DebugMap], "updateQueue": [Object]}, "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.6326139569282532, "actualStartTime": 174946767.862117, "alternate": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157251, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 2.172077000141144, "actualStartTime": 174949280.499117, "alternate": [Circular], "child": [FiberNode], "childLanes": 0, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Function MapView], "firstEffect": [FiberNode], "flags": 1, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "lastEffect": [FiberNode], "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": [Object], "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function ref], "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 1.1991539895534515, "sibling": [FiberNode], "stateNode": [Circular], "tag": 1, "treeBaseDuration": 3.0254620015621185, "type": [Function MapView], "updateQueue": [Object]}, "child": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157255, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [Circular], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 0.7919219732284546, "actualStartTime": 174946768.707117, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childLanes": 0, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Object], "firstEffect": [FiberNode], "flags": 1, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "lastEffect": [FiberNode], "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [Circular], "selfBaseDuration": 0.26892298460006714, "sibling": null, "stateNode": null, "tag": 11, "treeBaseDuration": 1.6707689762115479, "type": [Object], "updateQueue": null}, "childLanes": 0, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Function MapView], "firstEffect": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157560, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [Circular], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 0.21738401055335999, "actualStartTime": 174946769.273887, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childLanes": 0, "dependencies": null, "elementType": "RCTMGLAndroidTextureMapView", "firstEffect": null, "flags": 132, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function ref], "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.17261499166488647, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [ReactNativeFiberHostComponent], "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 1.1255379915237427, "type": "RCTMGLAndroidTextureMapView", "updateQueue": null}, "flags": 1, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 1, "lastEffect": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157259, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 0.4420759975910187, "actualStartTime": 174946769.150502, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childLanes": 0, "dependencies": null, "elementType": "RCTView", "firstEffect": [FiberNode], "flags": 4, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "lastEffect": [FiberNode], "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.21599999070167542, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [ReactNativeFiberHostComponent], "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 1.341537982225418, "type": "RCTView", "updateQueue": null}, "memoizedProps": {"attributionEnabled": true, "children": [Array], "localizeLabels": false, "logoEnabled": true, "onPress": [Function onPress], "pitchEnabled": true, "regionDidChangeDebounceTime": 500, "regionWillChangeDebounceTime": 10, "rotateEnabled": true, "scrollEnabled": true, "style": [Object], "surfaceView": false}, "memoizedState": {"height": 664, "isReady": true, "isUserInteraction": false, "region": null, "width": 360}, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": {"attributionEnabled": true, "children": [Array], "localizeLabels": false, "logoEnabled": true, "onPress": [Function onPress], "pitchEnabled": true, "regionDidChangeDebounceTime": 500, "regionWillChangeDebounceTime": 10, "rotateEnabled": true, "scrollEnabled": true, "style": [Object], "surfaceView": false}, "ref": [Function ref], "return": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157249, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 1.6546899378299713, "actualStartTime": 174946767.835963, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [Circular], "childLanes": 1, "dependencies": null, "elementType": "RCTView", "firstEffect": [FiberNode], "flags": 0, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "lastEffect": [FiberNode], "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.43476900458335876, "sibling": null, "stateNode": [ReactNativeFiberHostComponent], "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 124.73000481724739, "type": "RCTView", "updateQueue": null}, "selfBaseDuration": 0.8298459947109222, "sibling": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 157252, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": undefined, "actualDuration": 0.006691992282867432, "actualStartTime": 174946769.690194, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childLanes": 0, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Object], "firstEffect": null, "flags": 0, "index": 1, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 8, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0.5985389947891235, "sibling": [FiberNode], "stateNode": null, "tag": 11, "treeBaseDuration": 120.09238883852959, "type": [Object], "updateQueue": null}, "stateNode": [Circular], "tag": 1, "treeBaseDuration": 2.50061497092247, "type": [Function MapView], "updateQueue": {"baseState": [Object], "effects": null, "firstBaseUpdate": [Object], "lastBaseUpdate": [Object], "shared": [Object]}}, "context": {}, "logger": {"logCallback": null, "loggerEmitter": {"_disableCallsIntoModule": false, "_subscriber": [EventSubscriptionVendor]}, "startedCount": 1, "subscription": {"context": undefined, "emitter": [NativeEventEmitter], "eventType": "LogEvent", "key": 1, "listener": [Function anonymous], "subscriber": [EventSubscriptionVendor]}}, "props": {"attributionEnabled": true, "children": [<Camera … />, null, undefined, null, [Array]], "localizeLabels": false, "logoEnabled": true, "onPress": [Function onPress], "pitchEnabled": true, "regionDidChangeDebounceTime": 500, "regionWillChangeDebounceTime": 10, "rotateEnabled": true, "scrollEnabled": true, "style": {"flex": 1}, "surfaceView": false}, "refs": {}, "state": {"height": 664, "isReady": true, "isUserInteraction": false, "region": {"geometry": [Object], "properties": [Object], "type": "Feature"}, "width": 360}, "updater": {"enqueueForceUpdate": [Function enqueueForceUpdate], "enqueueReplaceState": [Function enqueueReplaceState], "enqueueSetState": [Function enqueueSetState], "isMounted": [Function isMounted]}}
```

Comment: What do you see for `this.map`? Can you just print log and see if this is real map object or not, also Can't real see any error in the provided code. would be nice if you add reproducible link

Comment: @Naren see the update...

Comment: You are using an inline callback ref so could be `null` on first invocation. Try `createRef`, turn the inline ref callback to a bound class method, or include an `if` in `onPress` to see if `this.map` is defined. Also, where are you importing `View`.

Comment: Check the caveats with callback refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs

Comment: Can you use `this._map` instead of `this.map`, If it works, I'll explain why if not, good luck . Weird but try once

Comment: @morganney no, the `this.map` object is neither `null` nor `undefined`. See the console output above

Comment: @Naren after renaming `map` to `_map` the same error occurs: `ERROR  TypeError: _this._map.moveTo is not a function.`. I saw this trick also earlier, but it had no effect.

Comment: If you somehow create reproducible stackblitz example, we can try to help. The above code isn't enough to find what went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `moveTo` method belongs to Camera object. [ref](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/Camera.md#movetocoordinates-animationduration).


I don't have the environment setuped to test. The code will look something like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';

MapboxGL.setAccessToken('xxxx');

export default class DebugMap extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.camera = React.createRef();
  this.map = React.createRef();

  this.handleOnpress = this.handleOnpress.bind(this);
 }

 handleOnpress(event) {
  const loc = event.geometry.coordinates;
  this.camera.current.moveTo(loc, 200);
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

    <MapboxGL.MapView ref={this.map} 
       onPress={this.handleOnpress} 
       style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     
     <MapboxGL.Camera ref={this.camera} 
        zoomLevel={10} 
        centerCoordinate={[50, 20]} />

    </MapboxGL.MapView>
   </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: I was using `useRef` which didn't work. `createRef` fixed it for me, thanks a ton for posting!